# What are the lib files in Poco C++

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I just began using Poco in C++, a languidness I'm new to. I seem to have compiled everything fine, but I'm at a loss as to what lib files to include. I'm working in `Eclipse CDT` with `MingGW` compiler (can I even use Poco with this?). When I look in the lib directory of the Poco file, this is the sort of thing I see:

```
PocoFoundationmd (Object file library)
PocoFoundationmdd (VC++ minimum rebuild de...)
PocoFoundationmdd (Object File Library)
pocoFoundationmdd (Program debug database)
PocoFoundationmt (Object file library)
PocoFoundationmtd (VC++ minimum rebuild de...)
PocoFoundationmtd (Object File Library)
pocoFoundationmtd (Program debug database)
```

It repeats the same type (The stuff I put next to them) for each section of the library (Foundation, Net, Util...)

Comment: You basically have to link against the *.lib files. a d suffix means debug build. mt means multithreaded c++/c runtime and md dll c++/c runtime. Also see http://pocoproject.org/docs/ POCO C++ Libraries Windows Platform Notes

Answer (score 7):

I went looking in the POCO docs and found the Library Naming Conventions, which may be what you were after (as in, to answer: What is the difference between the "mdd", "mt", "mtd" and so on versions?).

Source: http://pocoproject.org/docs/99150-WindowsPlatformNotes.html#3

Modified slightly to emphasise the filename endings. A "Poco{LIB}" example is "PocoFoundation"

### Library Naming Conventions

The following naming conventions are used:

- DLL import libraries are named Poco{LIB}**.lib** for the release build and Poco{LIB}**d.lib** for the debug build.
- Static libraries built using the static multithreaded C/C++ runtime libraries are named Poco{LIB}**mt.lib** (release) and Poco{LIB}**mtd.lib** (debug).
- Static libraries built using the DLL C/C++ runtime libraries are named Poco{LIB}**md.lib** (release) and Poco{LIB}**mdd.lib** (debug).

32-bit libraries are placed in the lib directory. 64-bit libraries are placed in the lib64 directory. DLLs are placed in bin (32-bit) or bin64 (64-bit). 64-bit DLLs are named PocoLIB64.dll for release and PocoLIB64d.dll for debug, respectively.

Comment: Hoe to build a debug version of Poco? Do I need to activate any flag or is there a debug version to build? thanks in advance